# SQLAlchemy: how to disable ORM-level foreign key handling on delete?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I've learned that SQLAlchemy implements some foreign key handling such as setting them null when the parent is deleted, separately from the database, meaning they can be set to different behaviors, and different ways of doing the same thing could get either one. Example:

I have `Comment` and `Subscription`, where `Subscription` has a foreign key relationship to `Comment`. I started by setting `backref = backref('subs', cascade = 'delete, delete-orphan')` on the `Subscription`'s relationship, and the result was that `session.delete(comment)` would delete the subscriptions on the comment properly, but `session.query(Comment).filter_by(id = id).delete()` would fail with a foreign key violation, because the cascade was set at the ORM level instead of the Postgres level.

Needless to say I find this very confusing, and I want to disable it so that all foreign key handling on deletes is done by Postgres. I'm not finding an obvious way to do it looking at the docs. I read about [passive deletes](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/collections.html#passive-deletes), which sounds like it does what I want except that it doesn't apply to objects already loaded into the session.

Is there a way to disable all ORM-level foreign key handling on deletes? And is there a good reason not to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Huh, I tried out passive deletes and it seems like it does what I need after all. The words "The `cascade="all, delete-orphan"` *will* take effect for instances of `MyOtherClass` which are currently present in the session" made me think that it would still manually issue deletes for dependent objects if they were added to the session, but if I fetch the depended object and then the dependent one and then modify the dependent, verifying that it's in `session.dirty`, and then delete the depended and commit, SQLAlchemy doesn't manually issue a delete for the dependent object.